# What are buildings used for recreation and lounging near marinas called? Something like a club house but only for private use

Tags: single-word-requests

What are buildings used for recreation and lounging, near marinas called? Something like a club house but only for private use. Generally owned by very wealthy people with yachts. The words coming to my mind are "lounge" and "outhouse", but I'm thinking of something on a grander scale.

Comment: *Cabanas* maybe?

Comment: Dan Bron, cabana would be more suitable for a small structure found near swimming pools.. I don't think I can use it to describe a place where people can rest after dismounting a yacht on a private island.

Comment: If you can afford such a building you can call it anything you want.

Comment: Lol, Hot Licks! It's for an article I am writing. If I were to own it I'd call it a freaking crack-house.

Comment: Surely the house used by the boat club is the clubhouse.

Comment: **bungalow** may be?

Comment: @choster I have at no point in my query mentioned that the building was to be used by a boat club.

Comment: @Graffito I think I will go with "clubhouse" pertaining to its usage as explained by Cary C and Chasly from UK, below. A bungalow, I feel, indicates more of a residential place than a more casual establishment for leisure.  Thanks anyway :)

Comment: In any other context than yachting, the structure, in the US, would be called a "cabin".

Comment: Hint:  Type "synonym cabin" in Google and take your pick.  I think "lodge" or "cottage" might work pretty well.

Comment: Note that "beach house" is the common term for a private house near a beach, but it doesn't convey the meaning of being associated with yachting.  This is the focus of nauseating TV shows such as [Beachfront Bargain Hunt](http://www.hgtv.com/shows/beachfront-bargain-hunt).

Answer (score 2):

In the UK the building that houses a yacht club is called the **clubhouse**, e.g.

[Brighton Marina Yacht Club Clubhouse](http://bmyc.uk/the-club/life-in-the-club-house/)

Note that in the UK, outhouse usually means something like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Amish_Outhouse.jpg

Comment: Is "clubhouse" a suitable term to describe a similar establishment but which is not open to public or membership?

Comment: @za-ah, in the US I would say so. The building is primarily used for recreation and relaxation, regardless of who is invited or allowed to use it - which is what earns it the 'club' part of the word (not that all clubs are for these purposes, but the term generally connotes something less formal that other sorts of organizations).

Comment: In the US a "clubhouse" generally belongs to the club.  The OP's structure is privately owned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a thing exists at a marina.  If it were a private beach or dock on private land, that would be different.

But as the author, you get to make up whatever you like.

**cabana** *a small cabin or tentlike structure for use as a bathhouse, especially on a beach or by a swimming pool* -- Random House.